# How to find the difference between two dates ? Calculate the find the difference between two Counts?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

```
DATE               Item              Count   
------------------------------------------
2018-03-15         Basketball        1000
2018-03-12         Basketball         950
2018-03-07         Basketball         900
2018-03-02         Basketball         850
```

These rows above belongs to different row position in a table they are sorted out like that using queries below and below queries are in a stored procedure.

What I am trying to do is find the number of Count difference and Number of day difference between two dates

```
select Top 1  Date, Item, Count 
from SportsItemSells 
where @Item ='BasketBall' 
order by DATE desc   -- returns first row

select Date, ITEM, Count 
from SportsItemsSells 
where @Item =Item
order by DATE desc
      offset 1 rows 
      fetch next 1 row only;   -- returns second row

Select Date, ITEM, Count 
from SportsItemsSells 
where @Item =Item
order by DATE desc
      offset 2 rows 
      fetch next 1 row only;   -- returns third row
```

When I TRY to calculate days difference between two dates in the stored procedure, it always returns zero

```
@DayDifferenceCalculation1 = DateDIFF( day,@Date,@Date)
```

What I want is `DateDiff(Day,@DateRow1,@DateRow2)` (*BUT HOW TO DEFINE dates dynamically for different dates and different rows?*)

```
@CountDifferenceCalculation1 = @Count - @Count (
```

again it returns zero always, no matter what.

What I want is

```
 @CountDifferenceCalculation1 = @Count1 - @Count2 )
```

but all those counts are set as `@Count` and Date as `@Date` how to define `@Date` and `@Count` for different Rows differently?

Any help will be appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n5WY.png)

Comment: It will be helpful if you give details of what you tried in store proc.

Comment: Please add source table data and  what you want as result .. that will help to see the possible ways.

Comment: when I try to find the difference between Days difference it always gives me zero since DATEDIFF(day,@Date,@Date) is always zero but I do not want it to be zero if we take difference between first row date and second row date it should give me 3 days difference

Comment: there are other rows in between above table for baseball,SoccerBALL, BUT I used those queries to select just for the basketball....those rows in above table could be anywhere in the table not one after another...so I used those  select queries in store proc....

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you needed ?

```
SELECT  Item,
        Date,
        LEAD(Date,1,null) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS NextDate,
        DATEDIFF(day,[Date],LEAD(Date,1,null) OVER (ORDER BY Date)) AS DateDifference,
        Count,
        Count-LEAD(Count,1,null) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS CountDifference

FROM #Temp1
```

And the result will be

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qb0U.jpg)

Comment: I actually want to select four rows from the table order by the recent dates....only for the basketball sell.....first row(the most recent date),the fourth row is the oldest date.......first row could be 50th row in the actual sell table and fourth row could be 100th row in actual table....what I want is Difference between Basketball Sell count for first and second, Days difference between first and second, first and third and first and fourth so we will have there values for sell counts and days difference..I just want these 3 values

Comment: @Jr.Developer You might place your pre-select into a `cte` and use this code against this *derived table*.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
WITH CTE_SportsItemSells AS
(
select  Date,Item,Count,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) Rn
from SportsItemSells 
WHERE Item='Basketball'
)
SELECT C.DATE AS MostRecentDate
,C2.Date AS NextDates 
,C.Item AS RecentCount
,C2.COUNT AS NextCounts
,DATEDIFF(DAY,C.Date,C2.Date) AS DateDifference
,C.Count-C2.Count AS 'CountDifference'
FROM CTE_SportsItemSells AS C
LEFT JOIN CTE_SportsItemSells AS C2 ON C.Rn<C2.Rn
WHERE C.Rn=1 AND C2.Rn<=4
```